# Finding Limit of n-th root sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

Disclaimer: I'm a starting-level-student.

How do I prove or deny this?
 $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n - n^2} = 2$$

I have a feeling that this expression doesn't getting closer to 2 but I can't find how to prove this.

I've tried 2 ways:

First -

$$|\sqrt[n]{2^n - n^2} - 2| < \epsilon$$ 
from the definition of limits, trying to evaluate this expression and deny it but I'm not getting anywhere.

So can I get some help on how to solve this ?

Comment: Really ??? Do you really mean that : $(a-b)^n=a^n-b^n$

Comment: If you know this fact: 'when $n\to\infty$ exponential growth wins over power growth' you can focus your attention to $2^n$ as $n^2$ is irrelevant

Comment: Are you familiar with the natural logarithm function?

Comment: @Dr.MV No, this is yet to be studied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: write your Limit in the form $$2\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$$

Comment: As note to make this more generally applicable, when dealing with $n$-th roots that contain multiple terms, one of which is raised to the power of $n$ or a multiple of $n$, it is useful to factor that out. A second example of doing this could be $\sqrt[n]{e^n + 2^n} = 2\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{e^n}{2^n} + 1} = 2e\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{1}{2^n} + \dfrac{1}{e^n}}$.

Comment: Thanks! but I guess I don't really understand How to get rid of the nth-square root?

Answer (score 2):

You may exploit the following inequality: if $a>b>0$, for any $n\geq 1$ we have
$$ n(a-b)b^{n-1}\leq a^n-b^n \leq n(a-b)a^{n-1}\tag{1}$$
*Proof*: it simply follows from $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+a b^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$.
 There are $n$ terms of the form $a^j b^k$ and each of them is $\leq a^{n-1}$ and $\geq b^{n-1}$due to $b<a$.

Now we may consider $a=2$ and $b=\left(2^n-n^2\right)^{1/n}$. We get
$$ 2-(2^n-n^2)^{1/n}\leq \frac{n^2}{n \left(2^n-n^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}\leq \frac{n}{2^{n/2}}\tag{2} $$
where the last inequality holds for any $n$ large enough. Now $(2)$ clearly proves that
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(2^n-n^2\right)^{1/n}=2 \tag{3} $$
as wanted.

---

$(1)$ might look as an overkill, but it is a useful inequality for proving, for instance,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{n}x^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^n e^{-x}\,dx = n! $$
leading to Euler's product formula for the $\Gamma$ function.